# Counting number of appearances of term in each value of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where a key is an id and the value is a list of strings.

I am interested in creating a subsequent dictionary from this, to store the frequency of each string. In this new dictionary, the key would be a word, and the value is the number of lists it appeared in, in the original dictionary.

```
freq_dict = {}
for key, value in dict.items():
   if word not in freq_dict:
        freq_dict[word] = 0
        freq_dict[word] += 1
        continue
   else:
        freq_dict[word] += 1
        continue
```

One issue I am having here is that if a word appears twice in a list, it will be counted twice. To fix this, I tried using `break` instead of `continue`, but then I would never count more than one word in each list.

What would be a good and efficient approach of achieving what I want? I though of converting every value to a `set` in the original dict, but that seems unreasonable for very large dictionaries.

Comment: Can there be duplicates within a single list and do you want to count them double?

Comment: can you share a sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
freq_dict = {}
for value in dct.values():  # don't call a variable dict
    for word in value:
        freq_dict[word] = freq_dict.get(word, 0) + 1
```

And if you don't want to count lists twice for words that may occur twice in them, just change the inner loop to:

```
for word in set(value):
```

Of course there are utils to make this easier:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

freq_dict = Counter(chain(*dct.values()))
# freq_dict = Counter(chain(*map(set, dct.values())))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list and dictionary comprehension.
Here an example for the following dct1:

```
dct1 = {1: ["Bla", "Foo", "Foo", "Baz"], 2: ["Bla"], 3: ["Foo", "Baz"], 4: ["Baz"], 5: ["Foo"]}
```

When using the following code you get the result you want:

```
#this flattens the dictionary to a one-level list where duplicates within one value list from dct1 are excluded
values_list = [entry for inner_list in [list(set(ls)) for ls in dct1.values()] for entry in inner_list]
#then you use a dictionary comprehension with the count function
dct2 = {string: values_list.count(string) for string in values_list}
```

dct2 then give you the following:

```
{'Foo': 3, 'Bla': 2, 'Baz': 3}
```